# How do you display Calendar's in Java in a human-readable way?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I have two array lists consisting of Calendar objects. I need these two lists to contain the same objects and in the same order - but this isn't the case. I ran the program on debugger mode to check the content of the lists but the object descriptions are gibberish. I just want to know if the year, month and day are the same at each step.

This is what my debugger shows:

[image]

When I click the arrow next to each index to reveal more information I still can't find what I need. Is there a way around this? Or perhaps there is another debugging tool that I am unfamiliar with? At this stage my debugging skills are limited to placing breakpoints and clicking the bug icon.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Right-click on one of those calendars.
- Choose Customize data views...
- Go to the second tab: Java data type renderers
- Click the + icon and name your renderer (calendar, for example)
- Type `java.util.Calendar` in the box "Apply renderer to objects of type..."
- Check the radio button "Use following expression"
- Type the following expression (for example): `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(getTime())`
- Click OK.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to deal with TimeZones, you can use this ampliation to JB Nizet solution:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(getTime()) + " " + getTimeZone().getDisplayName(false,TimeZone.SHORT) + " " + getTimeZone().getRawOffset()/3600000
```

Example output:

[image]

Shows the TimeZone name and the offset in hours

Answer (score 1):

Global configuration is also possible, go here to view all active detail formatter and to add new ones:
*Preferences* > *Java* > *Debug* > *Detail Formatter*

Qualified type name: `java.util.Calendar`

Detail formatter code snippet returns the String you defined, in my case german format of date + time:

```
this.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH ) + "." + 
(1 + this.get(Calendar.MONTH ) ) + "." + 
this.get( Calendar.YEAR )
```

This is what it looks like in preferences:
[image: detailFormatterCalendar]

Comment: Anyway to do this in Android Studio or Intellij IDEA?